# how to resolve MySQL Left WHERE condition error?

Tags: mysql, left-join, where-clause

The following statement gives the results without any error,

```
select 
title as 'unreviewed series', 
rating from series 
left join reviews 
    on series.id= reviews.series_id  
where rating is null;
```

However, the following gives an error:

```
select title as 'unreviewed series', 
ifnull(avg(rating), null) as 'Average Rating' 
from series 
left join reviews 
    on series.id= reviews.series_id  
where avg(rating) = null;
```

The error given by mysql is to use right syntax near WHERE.

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message? Please add it to the question

Comment: What do you want to do with `ifnull(avg(rating), null)`?

Comment: @forpas to get the string 'null' for the filtering. Is it redundant?

Comment: You will not get the string `'null'` but `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use having and group by - where will not work as you are trying to filter with aggregated function

```
select title as 'unreviewed series', 
ifnull(avg(rating), null) as 'Average Rating' 
from series 
left join reviews 
    on series.id= reviews.series_id  
group by title
having avg(rating) is null
```

Comment: you are trying to filter with aggregated function - so in this case where will not work @Arpanjain

Answer (score 1):

When you use aggregate function (like avg),you must use group by on other columns,
And when you use group by ,you must use having for set where clause on aggregated column
 Like this:

```
    select title as 'unreviewed series', 
ifnull(avg(rating), null) as 'Average Rating' 
from series 
left join reviews on series.id= reviews.series_id  
group by title
having avg(rating) is null
```